# com.google.gcloud.datastore vs com.google.appengine.api.datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, conflicting-libraries

I have been trying out google app engine for some time. Using their code samples of google datastore, I am presently developing an Uber like app to track the public bus movements. I am using `com.google.gcloud.datastore` presently but is quite restricted compared to `com.google.appengine.api.datastore`.

What is the difference b/w the two?

When should I use `com.google.gcloud.datastore` vs `com.google.appengine.api.datastore`?

Should I switch to `appengine.api.datastore`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code runs on App Engine, you should use the API built for the App Engine, whether it's a low level API that you mention or Objectify.

If your code runs outside of App Engine instances, you need to use gcloud.